# How to select multiple items in a TTreeView in code

Tags: treeview, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I'm trying to select all the child node of a parent node when the parent is clicked, but when I for each node set the Selected = true i only end up with the last one being selected.
MultiSelect is true and I can do it with the mouse, so the setup should be ok.

For testing I use this code:

```
TTreeNode *node = Tv->Items->GetFirstNode();
node->Selected = true;
node = node->GetNext();
node->Selected = true;
node = node->GetNext();
node->Selected = true;
node = node->GetNext();
node->Selected = true;
```

Any tricks to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

The `TTreeNode::Selected` property does not support multiple selections when toggling the node's selection state.  Internally, it will call the Win32 `TreeView_SelectItem()` API, which selects a single node only.

For multi-select, use the [`TTreeView::Select()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.Select) method instead:

> The select method selects one **or more** tree nodes.

That being said, your example is attempting to select (potentially) every node in the TreeView, not just the child nodes of a parent node, as you claim.

Try this:

```cpp
void AddNodeAndChildrenToList(TList *List, TTreeNode *Node)
{
    List->Add(Node);
    TTreeNode *child = Node->getFirstChild();
    while (child)
    {
        AddNodeAndChildrenToList(List, child);
        child = child->getNextSibling();
    }
}

...

TList *nodes = new TList;
try
{
    TTreeNode *parent = ...;
    AddNodeAndChildrenToList(nodes, parent);
    Tv->Select(nodes);
}
__finally
{
    delete nodes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy
It works perfect.